# How to import a ZIP file to Android Studio?

Tags: android, import, zip, android-studio

When I try to import a **ZIP folder** to the **Android Studio**, I always receive the message *"Cannot import anything from..."*. That phrase appears by all ZIP files and I can't find any solution to that problem. The ZIP files are from a tutorial. So how can I import those files to AS?

I hope you can help me

Comment: Is the zip file you want to import a library or what ?

Comment: Im sorry I'm still new. How do I know the difference?

Comment: Just browse what is the content of the ZIP file, if its a jar you can unzip and import it Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S and selecting the Plus Sign in the Libraries menu

Comment: you should extract the zip file, then import the project folder into Android Studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved it, thanks to Eefret. I extracted the Zip files and imported the folder that was in it.