# Importing a .zip File Into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, zip, project

Could someone please give me a step-by-step guide on how to get the .zip file into am Android Studuo Project? I know you must unzip the .zip file, but don't know what to import. I have been searching for the past 3.5 days trying to find how to do this, with no luck. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a ZIP file to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768633/how-to-import-a-zip-file-to-android-studio)

Comment: No, that just says that he needs to unzip it. I don't know what folder to open. The whole unzipped thing? Source code folder? Assets? I don't know

Comment: There should be a root folder. You could try to Import that.

Comment: Root folder? I need to know what to select when I import. I have a folder after I unzipped the .zip. Do I import the whole folder? Or something inside of it?