# Error in import of project to Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to import zip file to Android studio which I have downloaded from tutorial and it's almost done but when I tried to open the extracted folders in Android studio it's showing the error message like cannot run fit and project sync

Comment: Please try to add the errors that you are having there so that we can understand the type of error and can be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the file in Finder/File Explorer and then try importing the extracted files into Android Studio. See this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768633/how-to-import-a-zip-file-to-android-studio).